# Approve and disapprove a transaction

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, erc-20-approve, smart-contract

i want to develop a contract student in which student sign a transaction to update its record and owner would be able to approve or disapprove this transaction how would I able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sketch:

```
mapping(address=> bool) students;
mapping(uint256 => bool) isTransactionApproved;

modifier onlyStudent {
 require(students[msg.sender] === true, 'Only students');
_;
}

function approveTransaction(uint256 id) external onlyStudent {
 isTransactionApproved[id] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the student submit all the modifications they want to do in a transaction, store them somewhere in a `pendingModifications` array or something like that, idk. And have a function for the owner so they can approve/reject the changes, clearing the pending array and potentially modifiying the data.

Comment: yes student will call a function to update transaction.
Can you please write its code with two attributes name and id

Comment: No, i can't do your assignment for you, and you shouldn't really ask for that, actually.

Comment: @SairaRao Note that this queue/approve pattern is used in other smart contracts, like timelocks or multisigs. You can take a look in that direction if you want.